# Storybook: How to Document a Custom React Hook in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, storybook

I'm looking for a simple way to document Custom React Hooks, and [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/examples) has caught my intention as a clean and relatively easy way to document/demo components I write in React.

However, I can't seem to find any examples of how to document a Custom hook in Storybook.

Currently I have to create a wrapper component and redefine all my hook's arguments as the props, and also return some html.

Was wondering if there's another way that people have come up with to document hook usage, inputs and returned data (types, description, control values, etc.)...

If anyone has any experience with this, a simple example would be greatly appreciated!

ps: using storybook v6

Comment: What are you trying/wanting to document? What sort of documentation are you looking for?

Comment: @DrewReese updated OP to clarify a bit

Comment: I don't think there are any storybook addons that will automatically document your code for you. I generally write [jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/) syntax documentation. There is a [Docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/introduction) addon that helps create documentation *within* storybook. It "infers metadata values based on source code, types and JSDoc comments."